# Getting a Unexpected token : after a jsonp cb in Weather underground

Tags: javascript, callback, jsonp

I am trying to do a weather underground query by creating jsonp. In their official documents it says that cb is the callback name (https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=autocomplete-api&MR=1#using_results), however, I keep getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" error. I'm trying to do this in pure javascript but I am having no such luck and all of the examples that I have found are jquery methods. Any help would be appreciated.

This is an example of the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : aq?query=Sacramento?callback=cb:1"

Here is the javascript code:

```
var citySearch = document.getElementById("citySearchForm");
var search;

function searchFormFunc(e){

    jsonP = "?callback=cb";  
    cityName = document.getElementById('getCitiesInput').value;

    var cityNameJsonP = cityName + jsonP;

    var searchCityLink = "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=";
    search = searchCityLink.concat(cityNameJsonP);

    console.log(search);

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = search;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    function cb(data){
       console.log("fired");
       console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is going to be

```
http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=FOOBAR?callback=cb
```

a valid url via [their api](https://serbian.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=autocomplete-api) would be

```
http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=20500&cb=cb
```

You should be encoding the value and you should be using `&` for multiple querystring parameters.

```
jsonP = "&cb=cb";  
cityName = encodeURICompontent(document.getElementById('getCitiesInput').value);

var cityNameJsonP = cityName + jsonP;
```

Comment: @ epascarello  The &cb=cb did the trick. Thanks I was stuck there.

Comment: And the issue is you did not follow the documenation, it is cb, not callback

Comment: @guest271314, in my answer there is one, in the example showing what OP is doing, there are two.

Comment: @guest271314 That was the same answer, I just added updated URL that worked with their api and not the invalid callback.

Comment: @epascarello Not certain what you are trying to convey? Initially there was only the first URL, with a description following which was referencing how to change the URL; though from perspective here, was not entirely clear as to the first URL being incorrect. Presumably why you included second URL for disambiguation? You have updated the Answer to show both incorrect and correct approaches.